# Tag Inputs with typeahead with ng-bootstrap and Angular 8/Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap, angular8, typeahead

I am trying to implement tags-input with typeahead from ng-bootstrap (Bootstrap 4.3.1). Most of the examples online point to jQuery implementation. Is there an Angular way of doing this?